# pandas read csv is returning extra unknown column

Tags: pandas

I am creating a csv file from pandas dataframe by combining two lists using:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(list(zip(patients_full,  labels)),
                  columns=['id','cancer']) 

df.to_csv("labels.csv")
```

but when I read the csv back there is an unknown column `unnamed` that shows up ? how do I remove that ?

```
 Unnamed: 0          id  cancer
0            0  HF0953.npy       1
1            1  HF1058.npy       3
2            2  HF1071.npy       3
3            3  HF1122.npy       3
4            4  HF1235.npy       1
5            5  HF1280.npy       2
6            6  HF1344.npy       1
7            7  HF1463.npy       1
8            8  HF1489.npy       1
9            9  HF1490.npy       2
10          10  HF1587.npy       2
11          11  HF1613.npy       2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of the index column that is saved by default when you do `to_csv("labels.csv")`. As the index column in the data frame that you were saving didn't have a name, when you read your `read_csv("labels.csv")` it is treated as all other columns but with 'Blank' column named that is becoming `Unnamed: 0`. To avoid this you have 2 options:

Option 1 - not read the index:

```
read_csv("labels.csv", index_col=False)
```

Option 2 - not save the index:

```
to_csv("labels.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: there are two different cols, one is not index, it contains integer values.I am not exactly sure how it got populated in my dataframe

Comment: @olive I have modified the answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What that column is in your output is the index of the dataframe. To not include it in the output: `df.to_csv('labels.csv', index=False)`. More information is available on that method [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) in the pandas docs

Comment: it's not index col, it's an unknown col with integer values.